# Is there any alternative way of achieving below logic in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, u-sql

I have two tables -> tb1 and tb2.
I am performing left join operation on these tables using ID column and also i have one more condition such as one column is not equal to other column . 
Below is sample code

```
select * from tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id=tb2.id AND tb1.pid!=tb2.pid;
```

I am able to get results from above query.

But i need to know is there any alternate ways to get same result using sql.?

Comment: Hellp Harish. If you _need_ to know it, you must have a reason for using an alternative. What is the reason? Or do you ask just out of curiosity?

Comment: Yes it's of curiosity and also I am planning to implement this logic in usql, since usql doesn't support not equal to condition..

Comment: Does usql support the `NOT` operator?

Comment: look at `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Personally I think you should ask this with a `usql` tag if you plan to write something like this in usql. I am not familiar with usql, but reading up on it I am seeing operators other than equals used in where clauses. That would make this possible. I am hesitant to write this out here because I would again use the not-equals operator but then in the where clause, and you asked to not use the not-equals operator.

Comment: Is there any alternative way of specifying a title so people know what you're trying to do in sql?

Answer (score 2):

The actually SQL standard uses `<>` instead of `!=`.

```
select * from tb1 LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id=tb2.id AND tb1.pid<>tb2.pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to you not equal not working because of your join and join condition. 
if we create two tables and create like your query

```
create table t1(id int,pid int);
create table t2 (id int,pid int );
insert into t1 values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4);
insert into t2 values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4);

select t1.* from t1 left join
t2 on t1.id=t2.id and 
t1.pid!=t2.pid
order by t1.id 

id  pid
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

It returns all the values of 1st table, because LEFT JOIN returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

But if you put inner join in the same it will not return any row. so i think problem is not in the "not equal operator"

Comment: @HarishK yes you can use not in